# Apache module_headers remove csrftoken from cookie

Tags: apache, security, grails, xss

We recently scanned our application for open vulnerabilities and one of the report shows the chances of XSS attack because of absence of `HttpOnly` and `Secure` flag in our cookies.

So, as per the suggestion [here](https://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-apache/) which is to update apache configuration and add following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
</IfModule>
```

But, now we are facing an issue with our CSRF implementation saying invalid token/request because adding this line removes cookie from request headers and add `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=9833010B7C016CBBC37F64117E4BB0BF; Path=/; HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure` in reponse headers.

Cookie value before adding HttpOnly and Secure flag:

```
Cookie: csrftoken=xRbsYj0jq9lRnWoL7PC2RUoufOeLYhJsLCACSYVeArPx9d0qZg4Ox7mnmhZc0jEU; JSESSIONID=75D35C6FBF8BB5DF9DD7B0E13405E885
```

Set-Cookie value in response header after adding `HttpOnly` and `Secure` flag:

```
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=9833010B7C016CBBC37F64117E4BB0BF; Path=/; HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure
```

BTW, we are using Grails 2.5.4 application `useToken` in `<g:form useToken="true">` and `withForm` in action implementation.

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Oct 14 2015 14:20:21

I would really appreciate if you could help us debug and resolve the problem.

Thanks